# How to feed trained Python TensorFlow model with batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I have created an own model and I trained it with ImageTrainGenerator- from Keras using `flow_from_directory`.

Like this: [how to train model with batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050723/how-to-train-model-with-batches). Everything works fine, I checked the generated batches, and the pictures are as it has to be.

My problem is, that I want to use this trained model in online face detection. I crop the faces on desired width and height, I convert it into array, but the prediction is horrible.

I think that the live streamed image has to be the same as what the Imagetraingenerator creates (batches). Any idea how can I convert `cv2.imread(path)` image into batch to predict the class?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the batch dimensions to convert it to a batch with 1 sample: `np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It gets the input, but the prediction is not good. Any idea where I have to correct?

```train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    FACES_DIR,
    batch_size=25,
    target_size=(224,224),
    color_mode='rgb',
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical'
)``` 
The accuracy is 0.98 loss: 0.2 valid_acc: 0.8 valid_loss: 0.4